# Join more than four tables in sql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables with the following columns: More in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8776a0/2

```
request : {id,request_id, client_id, product_name, designation_date_1, can }
assigned_samples:{id,labref, user_id, stat}
users{id, fname, lname}
clients:{id, name}
tracking_table{labref, activity, added_date}
```

What I would like to do is join all these tables and come up with one big table containing all the data
when joining with tracking table, the condition is to check if activity column has given value like "a", 
if a matching row is not found, the date_added should be null else show the date_added

```
result table {labref, prod, desc_date, can, CONCAT(fname,' ',lname), date_added}

SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.can, r.designation_date_1, CONCAT(u.fname,' ', u.lname) as analyst, a_s.stat
FROM request r, assigned_samples a_s, user u, clients c
WHERE r.client_id=c.id
AND a_s.analyst_id = u.id
AND r.request_id = a_s.labref
AND r.client_id='2'
GROUP BY r.request_id
```

If i add a condition to the query, it returns the data, but the date_added is all the same which is wrong

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.can, r.designation_date_1, CONCAT(u.fname,' ', u.lname) as analyst, a_s.stat
FROM request r, assigned_samples a_s, user u, clients c, tracking_table t
WHERE r.client_id=c.id
AND a_s.analyst_id = u.id
AND r.request_id = a_s.labref
AND t.activity ='Authorizing COA Release'
AND r.client_id='2'
GROUP BY r.request_id
```

Comment: You need to use an outer join (left or right) to get all records from a table and the matching ones from another. But I do not understand why you use group by when you do not use any aggregate function, such as sum() and you list only a single field in the group by list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join condition` should be added for `tracking_table`.

Try this:

**SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a116f/1**

***(I slightly changed the input data for demo)***

```
SELECT r.request_id, r.product_name, r.can, r.designation_date_1, CONCAT(u.fname,' ', u.lname) as analyst, a_s.stat,
  date_added
FROM request r, assigned_samples a_s, user u, clients c, tracking_table t
WHERE r.client_id=c.id
AND a_s.analyst_id = u.id
AND r.request_id = a_s.labref
AND r.client_id='2'
AND r.request_id = t.labref
AND t.activity ='Authorizing COA Release'
```